# Best Library to read Excel sheet?

Tags: java, excel

I am looking for open source library to read excel sheet?
I found lot tutorial on Google, but want to know the library name and sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

best library is [apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) better way for manipulating with excel

for sample code visit [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/)

Comment: are you sure there is no other library to do this?

Comment: you were talking about best library thats why i suggest this